# Strip leading and trailing whitespaces within a string matched using regex in php

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a html string

```
$html = <p>I'm a para</p><b>  I'm bold  </b>
```

Now I can replace the bold tags with wiki markup(*) using php regex as:

```
$html = preg_replace('/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/', '*\1*', $html);
```

Apart from this I also want the leading and trailing whitespaces in the bold tag removed in the same php's `preg_replace` function.

Can anyone help me on how to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Varun

Answer (score 1):

Use `\s` symbol for that (`\s*` means that there could be 0 or more occurrences):

```
$html = preg_replace('/\<b\>\s*(.*?)\s*\<\/b\>/i', '*\1*', $html);
```

-I also suggest to use `i` modifier since html tags are case insensitive. And, finally, symbols `<` and `>` should be escaped for more safety (they are part of some regex construsts. Your regex will work without escaping them, but it's a good habit to escape them so be sure to avoid errors with that)

(edit): it seems I've misunderstood 'trailing/leading' sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
$html = preg_replace('~<b>\s*(.*?)\s*</b>\s*~i', '*\1*', $html);
```

`\s` in between the tags and the string to keep will strip away the spaces to trim. The `i` flag just for case insensitivity and I used `~` as delimiters so you don't have to escape forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

> Apart from this I also want the leading and trailing whitespaces in the **bold** tag removed

Easy enough this will do it just fine.

```
$html = preg_replace('/<b>\s+(.*?)\s+<\/b>/', '*\1*', $html);
```

See the [demo](https://eval.in/48710)